# Filter method for C++ data structures

Tags: c++, functional-programming

What is the best way to filter out all elements in a data structure that don't obey a certain predicate? i.e. a method similar to the "filter" methods in functional programming languages.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["filter" higher order function in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635260/filter-higher-order-function-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

STL has [`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and [`remove_copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy) algorithms.

Comment: And remember that "remove" in STL doesn't actually remove anything, just pushes the undesirables to the back of the bus.  **I'm looking at you, Rosa Parks!** ;)  You still have to call `container.erase(returnedIter, container.end())`.

Answer (score 0):

This 'should' work for every container class that has iterators. Using a pointer to show that the container WILL be changed going through the function.

UnaryFunction needs a return type bool. Although using proper STL functions might be smarter...

```
template <class Container,
          class UnaryFunction>
void filter( Container *container, UnaryFunction func )
{
    typedef typename Container::iterator iter; // g++ complains w/o typename
    for( iter elem(container->begin()); elem != container->end(); )
        elem = ( func(&*elem) ) ? (elem + 1)
                                : container->erase(elem);
}
```

Comment: It would be better using a reference instead of a pointer (it is clearer that the intention is modifying, not acquiring ownership). Also, this would be quite expensive for vectors, as for each single remove all elements from that position to the end of the vector, and also for deques as removal from the middle is an expensive operation for basically the same reasons. The only sequential container for which this is effective are lists.

Comment: @Rodriguez - Well, the point I was trying to make with reference was that you cannot overlook that you're passing in the actual array with the declaration `filter(&vec, someFunc)` whereas ´filter(vec, someFunc)´ might mislead some that don't bother looking at the function declaration. Secondly, I realize this is not the most opportune code for vectors or queues, but the OP specifically asked for a filter-function that works on all data structures- this does just that; we can argue over the efficiency. However, your points are valid and should be taken into consideration by the OP.

Comment: And because it uses `(elem + 1)`, it only works for random access containers. (Associative containers would require a manual erase loop with different logic in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using boost you can use the [boost.iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) library, which has [filter_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html) for your case. Even if you don't it is quite easy to write your own.